# Trying to delete a field from template in Sanity IO

Tags: sanity

I have a field that I added but it is unnecessary.  I ran a mutation to set the boolean value but now I want to remove the field entirely from the template.

What I tried to do, below, was a variation on the mutation I ran, this was also based on this post, https://www.sanity.io/schemas/batch-remove-a-field-3841897a, which I read but would not run for me instead producing all kinds of dependency issues that I did not want to waste time on.

```
curl 'https://<client_id>.api.sanity.io/v2021-06-07/data/mutate/<process.env>' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{"mutations": [{"patch": {"query": "*[_type == \"contribution\"]"}, "unset": "published"}]}'
```

What is the easiest way to mass remove this `published` field I added from the `contribution` template (it has already been removed from the schema)?

Just to be totally clear, this is what I am trying to get rid of without having to view every single entry

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your schema is structured somewhat like this:

```
{
  "name": "contribution",
  "type": "document",
  "fields": [
    // Other fields...
    {
      "name": "published",
      "type": "boolean",
      "description": "Indicates if the contribution is published or not"
    },
    // Other fields...
  ]
}
```

You can remove the "published" field from your schema using the Sanity.io CLI.

```
npm install -g @sanity/cli
sanity schema removeField contribution.published
sanity deploy
```

Comment: is that the whole command?  This doesn't feel right looking at it,  this looks like it will delete the contributions that have published set to true instead of cleaning out the published field.  Maybe my question was not clear enough, I updated it to make sure.

Comment: Does that remove it from the entry though?  I already removed the field from the schema file but because it has data in it every entry I view has a warning that I have to click on to remove the field, plus not sure what version I need for this but that schema command does not run for me.  It returns `Error: Command "schema" is not available outside of a Sanity project context.
Run the command again within a Sanity project directory, where "sanity"
is installed as a dependency.` which is odd because I can run other sanity commands like sanity deploy just fine. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: You can use the unset() function to remove the field

Comment: My question is more like, how do I use `unset` to do this on a mass level, I understand `unset` is what I am looking to use.  Thanks again for the help